# Android Mp4 video Not playing

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have video that is locally stored in assets folder. Here is my code. I am getting error cannot play video. It is .mp4 file. It plays perfectly on my macbook.

```
Uri video = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/video");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, video)
intent.setDataAndType(video, "video/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Play Video"));
```

I have also placing it in raw folder, In this case I am not getting ActiviyNotFoundException

```
Uri video = Uri.parse("file:///android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video);
```

Answer (score 0):

The assets directory is private to your application; other applications cannot access it.

You will either need to provide access to the file using a [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html), or copy the file to a directory that other applications can access.

Comment: Is there any way I can place video in private location and play it using media player?

Comment: Internally in your app? You can use the SDK's VideoView, or for more granularity, MediaPlayer in conjunction with a SurfaceView. A more modern approach would be using ExoPlayer. The only way I'm aware of providing other applications access to private directories is through FileProvider.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play from sdcard then the try this.

```
Uri vidFile = Uri.parse("link");
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
videoView.setVideoPath(path);
videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
videoView.start();
```

path can also be retrieved by `MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA` or you can type the path as `/sdcard/videos`

Also have a look at [this](http://mrbool.com/how-to-play-video-formats-in-android-using-videoview/28299) tutorial

Comment: My video is not placed on sdcard, it is private to my application.